# Concavity, martingales and stopping time

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $(x_t)_t$ is a bounded $\mathbb F_t$ martingale and $f(t,x)$ is continuous, bounded, and concave in $x$. So, for any $s \ge t$, $$\mathbb E_t f(s,x_s) \le f(s,\mathbb E(x_s)) = f(s,x).$$

Does an analogous property also hold for any bounded $\mathbb F_t$ stopping time? More precisely, suppose $T \in (0,\infty)$ is a constant. Then, given any $\mathbb F_t$ stopping time $\tau$ such that $\tau \le T$ a.s., is it the case that, for any $t$ $$\mathbb E_t f(\tau, x_\tau) \le \mathbb E_t f(\tau, \mathbb E_t (x_\tau)) = \mathbb E_t f(\tau, x)$$

Comment: Is it $\tau \le T$ you want to assume, or $\tau \le t$?

Comment: No, $\tau \le T$ where $T \in (0, \infty)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $\mathbb{F}_t$ is the underlying filtration and $\mathbb{E}_t(\cdot)$ stands for $\mathbb{E}(\cdot | \mathbb{F}_t)$. Also, $f(s, x)$ in the right-hand side should read $f(s, x_t)$.

I also leave aside technicalities, such as whether $x_\tau$ is measurable (which, as far as I remember, may fail to be true unless one chooses a, say, càdlàg version of $x_t$ and extend the filtration in the usual way), and assume that the filtration and the martingale satisfy the usual regularity conditions.

Even assuming all the necessary regularity, the answer is negative, as shown by the following counter-example. Take $x_t$ to be the process which starts at $0$ and makes a $\pm 1$ jump at $t = 1$. Set $\tau = 2$ if this jump was positive, and $\tau = 3$ otherwise. Finally, define $f(t, x) = g(t) x$, where $g$ is a continuous function satisfying $g(2) = 1$ and $g(3) = 0$. Then
$$ \mathbb{E}_0 f(\tau, x_\tau) = \mathbb{E}(g(\tau) x_\tau) = \tfrac{1}{2} g(2) \times 1 + \tfrac{1}{2} g(3) \times (-1) = \tfrac{1}{2} , $$
but
$$ \mathbb{E}_0 f(\tau, x_0) = \mathbb{E}(g(\tau) \times 0) = 0 . $$

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I should have been more specific in that $x_s$ is actually a diffusion and hence satisfies the measurability requirements you mentioned. What I don’t get however is the third summand being negative. Why is $f_t$ concave in $x$ I don’t see. In fact, if $f_t \le 0$, as is the case in my problem actually, then $f_t$ is actually convex in $x$.

Comment: @avk255: My bad! Indeed, the "proof" that I gave was completely wrong, and in fact the answer is negative. Unless I made another mistake...

Comment: Great. This is very helpful. One thing that bothers me a bit is this seems to violate the optional stopping theorem. Your $f(t,x)$ is a supermartingale if $g(.)$ is a decreasing function as $Ef(t,X_t)= g(t) X_0 \le g(0) X_0$. So, shouldn’t we have the same inequality for any a.s. finite stopping time?

Comment: So, I got it wrong. With $t$ in there we don’t an analogous optional stopping.